# How to read certain data from CSV / .TXT files into a table

Tags: php, html, csv, post, text

I know there are many tutorials I tried nearly all of them, but it doesn't seem to be working, there is a .txt file (now i converted it to .csv in hope it will work but it didn't).

This file contains data separated by `;`'s the first line contains the names of certain things and the other lines are the records.

What I want is to read and display the RIGHT data regarding to the correct work id and customer id that can be inserted into an HTML form and displaying an HTML table after it ran but unfortunately, it doesn't work for some reason. Here are the codes:

First here is the HTML form's code:

```
 <h2>Device's status </h2>
                    <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="process.php">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="customerid" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Customer ID">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="workid" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Worksheet ID">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-submit" value="Submit">
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

And now the process.php:

```
<?php
$workid     = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['workid'])); 

$customerid       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['cusomterid'])); 

$file = file('WEBDATA.csv');

foreach($file as $line){

    list($workid,$customerid,$devicename,$devicesnumber,$manufactured,$offer,$grosspay;$status)= explode(";",$line);

}
?>



     <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td> Worksheet ID </td>
            <td> Customer ID</td>
            <td> Device Name</td>
            <td> Serial Number</td>
            <td> Manufacturer</td>
            <td> Expected Price </td>
            <td> Gross Final Price </td>
            <td> Repairing status </td>
            <tr>
                        <td><?php echo "$workid" ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo "$customerid" ?>   </td>
                        <td><?php echo "$devicename" ?>   </td>
                        <td><?php echo "$devicesnumber" ?>   </td>
                        <td><?php echo "$manufactured" ?>   </td>
                        <td><?php echo "$offer" ?>   </td>
                        <td><?php echo "$grosspay" ?>   </td>
                        <td><?php echo "$status" ?>   </td>
```

What is the problem? how to make this work? to be simple: the user puts in 2 ids  into that HTML form and it should display the data regarding to those 2 ids from the .csv file. but it doesnt work.

Comment: It's a typo `$grosspay;` <<< that's supposed to be a comma and checking for errors would have thrown you `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')'`. Typos are off-topic.

Comment: Thanks Fred, i translated all the stuff to English to be more understandable to everyone sorry for the typo.

Comment: just change `$manufactured,$offer,$grosspay;$status)` to `$manufactured,$offer,$grosspay,$status)` and it will work for you Steve. and remember to close off your table with `</table>` if you don't have it. It's not in your posted code.

Comment: no no unfortunately its not that simple, i made this typo here only i checked it when it runs it doesn't show anything just the empty table :(

Comment: I've tested your code with `John; 123; The device for John; 1234-ft-550; Bell & Howell; $9.99; $11.99; DONE;` in a csv file since I don't know what yours looks like. However I can understand why it wouldn't work the way you want it to, since it will show up the data even if an incorrect id/name is entered. TBH, I haven't worked with text files in years, ever since I started using a database, which in this case would make more sense. Now, if you can't get anything from it, then make sure that file has permissions set to read it and that you're reading the right file. Check for errors also.

Comment: instead of explode you should use the built in csv handling functions: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php etc

Comment: tried with str_getcsv still wont work :/ and the file is fully readable

Comment: I see what you mean now. I only had the one line of text in there. When I entered a new line of (new) data, it wouldn't bring up the actual id-related records, but only the last line of data in the file. However, it did not show anything if there was an extra carriage return in the file, so that may be why you're not seeing anything at all. There should not be any new lines after the last one, or more than one. TBH, I don't know how you can pull records from using id's with your form, sorry. It's been too long for me with a system like this.

Comment: i see i checked i have a total of 1806 lines including the first one, but i dont have any more " empty " lines under the last one

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you guys have not noticed or I don't understand fully the question but when I make these changes, it run smoothly and giving table with data.

```
<?php
$workid     = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['workid'])); 
$customerid       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['cusomterid'])); 
$file = file('WEBDATA.csv');
?>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td> Worksheet ID </td>
        <td> Customer ID</td>
        <td> Device Name</td>
        <td> Serial Number</td>
        <td> Manufacturer</td>
        <td> Expected Price </td>
        <td> Gross Final Price </td>
        <td> Repairing status </td>
    <tr>
<?php
foreach($file as $line){
    list($workid,$customerid,$devicename,$devicesnumber,$manufactured,$offer,$grosspay,$status)= explode(";",$line);
?>
        <td><?php echo "$workid" ?></td>
        <td><?php echo "$customerid" ?>   </td>
        <td><?php echo "$devicename" ?>   </td>
        <td><?php echo "$devicesnumber" ?>   </td>
        <td><?php echo "$manufactured" ?>   </td>
        <td><?php echo "$offer" ?>   </td>
        <td><?php echo "$grosspay" ?>   </td>
        <td><?php echo "$status" ?>   </td>             
<?php   } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: there was a typo near the customerid at the beginning of ur code but i tried it, and still it runs then no error messages just an empty table :( tested with 3 web browsers but still, :/